# Send email when value in cell changes in more than one cell on the same spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have searched and search stackoverflow for the answer to my question but have not found it. I am looking for anyone to help me fix my script below (which as is does work):

```
function sendEmail() {
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('IDP & Observation');
if (sheet.getRange('H20').getValue()!== 2){
return;
}
const emailAddress = sheet.getRange('C46').getValue();
const subject = sheet.getRange('C47').getValue();
const body = sheet.getRange('C48').getValue();
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body);
}
```

What I need to do is add another cell 'H34' which I have on the same sheet and need the same email sent when 'H34' changes to a value of 2 - and potentially I may want to do the same when a cell changes on another sheet within the google workbook to send the same message and so on.

So how can I add 'H34' as a value to trigger the same email??

Would I just add a line like this?

```
(sheet.getRange('H34').getValue()!== 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What your code means is:

- If the value of cell H20 doesn't equal two.
- Stop the function and return nothing.

```js
if (sheet.getRange('H20').getValue()!== 2){
   return;
}
```

---

You can combine multiple [conditions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) using [logical operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp).

`&&` is AND.
`||` is OR.

So this means:

- Create [variables](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp) (`const`) to store the value of h20 and h34
- If the value of h20 doesn't equal 2 **AND** the value of h34 doesn't equal two
- Stop running the function and return.

```js
const h20 = sheet.getRange('H20').getValue();
const h34 = sheet.getRange('H34').getValue();

if (h20 !== 2 && h34 !== 2){
   return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for teaching me this.  I am going to see if I can do something like you taught me and answer my own question with my new script.  Will you please look it over and correct me if needed?

Comment: Also, looking at what you taught me... what if I made the value === instead of !== would I then just delete the {return} ??  Like... const h20 = sheet.getRange('H20').getValue();
const h34 = sheet.getRange('H34').getValue();

if (h20 === 2 && h34 === 2);
}

Answer (score 0):

What if I did this?  Would this work?

```
function sendEmail() {
const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('IDP & Observation');
const h20 = sheet1.getRange('H20').getValue();
const h34 = sheet1.getRange('H34').getValue();

if (h20 !== 2 || h34 !== 2){
   return;
}

const emailAddress = sheet1.getRange('C46').getValue();
const subject = sheet1.getRange('C47').getValue();
const body = sheet1.getRange('C48').getValue();

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body);


const sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Yr 1 CSTP Co-Assessment');

const k63 = sheet2.getRange('K63').getValue();
const k68 = sheet2.getRange('K68').getValue();
const k73 = sheet2.getRange('K73').getValue();

if (k63 !== 2 || k68 !== 2 || k73 !== 2){
   return;
}

const emailAddress2 = sheet2.getRange('C147').getValue();
const subject2 = sheet2.getRange('C148').getValue();
const body2 = sheet2.getRange('C149').getValue();

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress2, subject2, body2);
}
```